# non linear fitting

Tags: curve-fitting, least-squares, nonlinear-functions, levenberg-marquardt

I have some experimental data and I would like to fit them to obtain my parameters using the least-square method (Levenberg-Marquardt).

I am using two non-linear equations and I am using some computational programs (Origin and Matlab).

The first is:

```
y=A+B*(((2*pi*x)^2+Alfa4^2)*((2*pi*x)^2+Alfa5^2))/(((2*pi*x)^2+Alfa1^2)*((2*pi*x)^2+Alfa2^2)*((2*pi*x)^2+Alfa3^2));
```

Non-linear equation with the parameters (Alfa1,Alfa2,Alfa3,Alfa4,Alfa5)

And the second fitting equation is:

```
y=((T2^2+Lc^2*(2*pi*x)^2)/(((2*pi*x)^2*(Lc^2*(2*pi*x)^2+T8))+T6^2))*A1+G;
```

Rational function, i.e. quadratic function on the numerator and a 4th polynomial function on the denominator

I want to fit using this two equations, but I dont know how to do it. If someone want the experimental data I can post here.

Thank you very much,

Eduardo

Comment: Try MATLAB curve fitting toolbox

Comment: I am already using, but when I creat a new fit with the first and the second equation, in the option "custom equations" insede the ToolBox, the MatLab2009 or 2012 (I have the two licenses) give me the same results, i.e., a wrong fitting adjust where the chi-square for example is negative and the Standard Deviation is bigger than my parameter!!